# python subprocess executing SAS program - permission denied

Tags: python, excel, permissions, sas

I wrote a python program that upload an excel file to SAS dataset on server. I tested it on my laptop and a few other people's laptop it worked fine. But when I was testing that on one of my colleague's PC I got the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "call_sas_program.py", line 56, in
    subprocess.call(["sasgsub", "-gridsubmitpgm", upload_excel.sas])
    File "/opt/packages/anaconda/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 523, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
    File "/opt/packages/anaconda/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in init errread, errwrite)
    File "/opt/packages/anaconda/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
    OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I used python's "subprocess". It looks like a permission issue with the subprocess, but I suspect it's the permission to create SAS table. Has anyone run into this problem before? And how to solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: no, it's a problem with `"sasgsub"`. Do you have a directory called that? and it seems you're running Linux (or maybe a Bash within windows) considering the paths. Where is `"sasgsub"` located in your system and which extension ?

Comment: Are the system paths defined identically on both computers?

Comment: Hi Jean-François Fabre is the sasgsub a module in the Python subprocess or is it something to do with the SAS configuration? I cannot find any directory or file called sasgsub but it ran fine when I executed it on my company's server